# How is the kernel modules loaded at boot time if no entry given in /etc/modules-load.d/ and /etc/modprobe.d?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have an `Ubuntu` machine which shows

```
root@test:/etc# lsmod | tail
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
net_failover           20480  1 virtio_net
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
drm                   622592  3 drm_kms_helper,cirrus
psmouse               176128  0
i2c_piix4              32768  0
virtio_blk             20480  1
failover               16384  1 net_failover
pata_acpi              16384  0
floppy                118784  0
```

But none of the above modules has an entry in the `/etc/modules-load.d` or `/etc/modprobe.d`.

My question is how these modules are loaded if they don't have its entry in the above directories?

Answer (score 2):

Some modules are loaded because other modules depend on them. In your example, `failover` was loaded because `net_failover` requires it, and `net_failover` because `virtio_net` requires `net_failover`. The 4th column of the `lsmod` listing indicates dependencies like these.

If the hardware information is supplied by firmware (e.g. ACPI or DMI) or the hardware is autoprobeable (e.g. PCI/PCIe or USB buses or the CPU type), then the kernel can autoload modules for them.

Run `sudo modprobe -c | less` and look for a long list of `alias` lines after the line:

```
# End of configuration files. Dumping indexes now:
```

Basically, the kernel modules have alias information embedded in them to describe the hardware they support using identifiers that the firmware or the bus-specific autoprobe mechanisms can supply. The module tools will gather this information into an index and make it part of the configuration for `modprobe`.

Once the kernel is probing for hardware, it will use any firmware-provided information or hardware autoprobe results to generate module loading requests using names formatted in a way specific to each firmware or bus type. If one of the listed aliases match what the kernel is requesting, the respective module gets loaded.

There is also the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, which can be used to specify a list of modules that should be included into initramfs and loaded before even trying to mount the root filesystem.

In your specific case:

- `crypto_simd` was loaded as a dependency for `aesni_intel`, which was probably loaded using a CPU-type-specific autoprobe alias.
- `cryptd` was required to be loaded by two modules, `crypto_simd` (see above) and `ghash_clmulni_intel`, which was probably loaded by a CPU-type-specific autoprobe alias.
- the `cirrus` GPU module was probably autoprobed by PCI ID, and then required `drm_kms_helper` and `drm` as dependencies. `drm_kms_helper` also specified its own dependency on `drm`.
- `psmouse`, `pata_acpi` and `floppy` were probably autoprobed by ACPI firmware information
- `i2c_piix4` was probably autoprobed by its PCI device ID.
- `virtio_blk` was probably autoprobed by a VirtIO-specific detection mechanism, same as `virtio_net`. VirtIO defines a "virtual bus" which is itself detectable by either ACPI information or by PCI device IDs, and once the virtio bus driver is loaded (or already embedded in the main kernel), it will have its own method for querying the hypervisor/hostOS for available VirtIO features. Based on responses to the query, the kernel has requested for `virtio_blk` and `virtio_net` to be loaded.